# Rebooting AWS EC2 instance restored my app to an old version

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have hosted a CakePHP app in EC2 using Elastic Beanstalk. Due to some performance issues I had to restart the server. Now I have lost all the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you reboot the instance or stop and start it?

If you rebooted it then it's certain your app and data are there.

If you stop and start an instance-store instance (not EBS-backed), then you will loose all your data on the ephemeral volume.

All this is well explained on the following link, take a look at it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Storage.html.